# Operational Amplifier - Avd - Aol Characteristic

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am looking on "Malvino Electronic Principles" and it writes that the "Aol" (Open Loop Gain) is 94dB. I am looking on TL082 datasheet and I find the parameter "Avd -Large-signal differential voltage amplification". The "Avd" is like "Aol" or something entirely different? Also, the Avd is measured in V/mV and not in dB? Could anyone explain me if there is a correspondence between V/mV and dB?

TL082 Datasheet:
http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/tl082

[image]

Comment: Can you link to the datasheet using "Avd"? TL082 is made by a lot of different manufacturers and the 1st hit in google (TI's) doesn't use that notation.

Comment: If I solve the equation: Voltage (dB) = 20*log( Vout/Vin ) = 20*log( 200V / 0.001V ) ≈ 106dB. This numbers that I put on the equation are right and if are right why on the Malvino book tells that the Aol of the TL082 is 94dB?

Comment: Thanks, it was some kind of [embarrassing] search fail inside the TI's pdf for me.

Answer (score 1):

dB by itself is a unitless ratio between a measured quantity and an established reference.  It's short for deciBel, where one Bel is defined to be a factor of 10 more power.  Thus, dB for power = 10*log(Measured/Reference)

Because we don't want to confuse our meters by having a different scale for power and signal (seeing that power ~= signal^2), we change the equation instead.  Using the properties of logarithms, we can convert log(x^y) into y*log(x) and get dB for signal = 20*log(Measured/Reference)

Given that information, you can easily convert between V/mV and dB.

---

As a side-note, there are lots of dB scales that imply the reference so as to use a single number to describe a measurable quantity.  For example:

- 0dBm = 1 milliwatt
- 0dBu = the voltage required to push 0dBm into 600 ohms** (~0.7746 volts rms)
- 0dBV = 1 volt rms
- 0dBSPL = 20 micropascals rms (rough lower limit of human hearing)
- 0dBA = 0dBSPL as measured on the same equipment but after a specific "A-weighting" filter (supposed to approximate human perception but grossly misunderstood and misused by the general public)
- 0dBFS = full scale, maximum level without clipping/distorting (actual level may vary wildly across different equipment, but this unit is very useful for signal integrity within each piece of equipment)
- Etc.

** In case you're wondering, 600 ohms is roughly the characteristic impedance of old telegraph wires on wood poles.  Even though it seems arbitrary now, the unit has survived and continues to influence modern designs.

---

I'm not going to comment on "Aol" or "Avd" or other manufacturers' terminology without seeing datasheets.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sloa083/sloa083.pdf (p. 13)

> Large signal differential voltage amplification, AVD, is similar to the open loop gain of the amplifier except open loop is usually measured without any load. This parameter is usually measured with an output load.  Figure 11–11 shows a typical graph of AVD vs. frequency

[image]

For the TL082 datasheet posted that AVD was measured with a greater than 2Kohm load.

Regarding

> If I solve the equation: Voltage (dB) = 20*log( Vout/Vin ) = 20*log( 200V / 0.001V ) ≈ 106dB. This numbers that I put on the equation are right and if are right why on the Malvino book tells that the Aol of the TL082 is 94dB?

Malvino probably used the minimum value (for all but the "C" model) of 50V/mV = 94dB. That's just a guess. There's a lot of TL082 datasheets out there. It's possible that old datasheets had a different typical value too; also this textbook has a bazillion editions, so who knows when Malvino put those in and from where. You could ask him by email. Textbooks are not free of errors; that's what book errata are for...

Comment: The link is dead. Maybe this can replace the old app-note: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa011/sloa011.pdf